# Detect and close all dialogs

Tags: dialog, add-in, excel-addins

I created an add-in in Excel 2010. There are a few buttons in the add-in, each button will display a dialog, so at same time there can be more than one dialog displayed, all modaless (this is part of the requirement not to be modal).

Now what I want to achieve is that, how do I close all other opened dialogs if I click on a button in one of the dialogs?

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple: issue close/hide/unload/whatever on all dialogs whether they are open or not.  If any throw an error, handle it.